# How do I access data returned from an axios get to display on a web page using Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have ajax functions in an api to which I'm making an axios get request from my Vue.js component. How can I access the returned data to display it on the web page with something like a conditional rendering?

Comment: Assign the relevant portion of the response to a `data` property. You'll need to include some example code if you need more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: With my call I get a response from my bd, so I wanna display this data in a container side by side input field